# ¿Por que ajax funciona con metodo post pero no con put en laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel, ajax

Tengo un problema muy extraño con laravel resulta que eh estado trasteando un poco con fetch para enviar solicitudes ajax. Entonces cree esta funcion para enviar mis solicitudes con ajax

```
function fetchRequest(op) {
    const { url, method, data, isFormData, successCallback, errorCallback } = op;
    console.log("Fetching:", url, method); 

    const headers = {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document
            .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
            .getAttribute("content"),
    };

    if (!isFormData) {
        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    }

    const options = {
        method,
        headers,
        body: isFormData ? data : JSON.stringify(data),
    };

    fetch(url, options)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`Error en la solicitud: ${response.statusText}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((responseData) => successCallback(responseData))
        .catch((error) => errorCallback(error.message));
}
```

Si por ejemplo uso el metodo `POST` del ajax funciona como deberia. Esta es la funcion con post:

```
function createPlatform(){
    const form = document.querySelector("#formCreatePlatform");

    if (form) {

        form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(form);

            fetchRequest({
                url: "/admin/platforms/",
                method: "POST",
                data: formData,
                isFormData: true,
                successCallback: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                errorCallback: function (error) {
                    toastifyAlerts(error, "error");
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                },
            });

        });
    }
}
```

y su controller

```
    public function store(Request $request){
        return response()->json($request);

    }
```

Bastante simple solo queria ver que los datos enviados desde el form lleguen al controller.
Ahora el problema es cuando uso el metodo `UPDATE`.

```
function updatePlatform() {
    const formUpdate = document.querySelector("#formUpdatePlatform");

    if (formUpdate) {


        formUpdate.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            const id = document.querySelector("#id_platform").value;
            const formDataUpdate = new FormData(formUpdate);

            fetchRequest({
                url: "/admin/platforms/" + id,
                method: "PUT",
                data: formDataUpdate,
                isFormData: true,
                successCallback: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                errorCallback: function (error) {
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                },
            });

        });
    }
}
```

Practicamente es un copia y pega de la funcion js para crear. Su controller igual es bastante simple solo tengo esto.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        return response()->json($request);
    }
```

Sin embargo en este caso del update no me esta llegando ningun dato al servidor solo me encuentro con un array vacio. No entiendo por que este problema si ambos metodos son practicamente iguales. No hay errores en consola ni en el log de laravel simplemente no me llega ningun dato al backend. No se que podria estar mal.
Por ultimo estas es la ruta

```
Route::resource('/admin/platforms', PlatformsController::class)->names('platforms');
```

Por mas que cambie cosas sigo con este problema no entiendo que esta mal porque solo funciona en el metodo post pero un put no. ¿Que podria estar mal?

Comment: El problema probablemente es que PUT no es un valor válido para HTML. Entonces tienes que usar  ```method: 'POST'``` y enviar una variable ```_method='PUT'``` para que Laravel escoja la ruta correcta https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: En HTML no se puede declarar PUT como METHOD. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @AlexAngelico pero si fuera ese el problema deberia mandarme un mensaje en consola de metodo no encontrado. Igual por si acaso lo probe y tampoco funciona todo sigue igual.